# Errors in validator

Tags: html, validation

I, getting a lot of errors in validator but I don't understand the reasons of it.

1. end tag for "form" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified
2. required attribute "action" not specified

```html
<div class="serch_block">
  <form method="post" action="/search">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form_in" name="search" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="image" src="/design/img/button.jpg" name="submit" style="width:20px;height:19px;" onfocus='this.value="";' value="Поиск" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

3. document type does not allow element "span" here; missing one of "th", "td" start-tag

```html
<tr>
  <td width="30" valign="top" align="right" class="text2" style="padding-top:10px;padding-right: 62px;">Email:</td>
  <td><input type="text" class="form_in" name="email" /></td>
  <span id="error_email" style="color:#ff0000;" class="<?php if(!isset($errors['email']))echo 'invisible';?>">Name and / or E-mail / are required!</span>
</tr>
```

Can you help me with it?

Comment: What doctype do you use?

Comment: Can't see the issue regarding the form. That seems fine to me. But the span in the table row is definitely wrong. It should be inside a <td> tag.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Answer (score 0):

Here is the form.

```html
<form action="/" method="post">
        <table align="center" border="0">
          
            <tr class="boss">

                <td width="30" valign="top" align="left" class="text2news">Имя:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form_in" name="name"  />
                    <span id="error_name" style="color:#ff0000" class="invisible"></span>  </td>
                <!--</td> -->

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  width="30" valign="top" align="right" class="text2" style="padding-top:10px;padding-right: 62px;">Email:</td>
                <td ><input type="text" class="form_in" name="email" /></td>
                <span id="error_email" style="color:#ff0000;" class="invisible">Имя и /или E-mail/ обязательны для заполенения!</span>

            </tr>
            <tr class="registrationBot">
                <td><input type="submit"  name="subscribe" value="подписаться" /></td>
                <td><input type="submit"  name="unsubscribe" value="отписаться" /><input type="submit"  name="cleenerror" value="закрыть" /></td>
               
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="color:#ff0000"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```